# My browser freezes when doing a for loop where I have to trim my integer

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, parsing, trim

My following code needs to execute a alcohol percentage, this outputs like 43,000004 at some point so I'd like to trim my data to 43,0, 45,3 etc.
But every time I execute any trim/parse functions from JavaScript, my browser freezes.

Here's my code:

```js
incrementAlcohol() {
  // Create a variable as an array.
  let alcoholData = []

  // Loop through the array until you achieve 40 till 95.
  for (let i = 40; i <= 95; i + 0.1) {
    // Split the first 3 integers in the string to remove the decimals.
    parseFloat(i).toFixed(3)

    // Parse it into a string for the autocomplete component.
    i.toString()

    // Push it into the array.
    alcoholData.push({
      'id': i,
      'name': i + "%"
    })
  }

  // Return the age.
  return alcoholData
},
```

Comment: `i + 0.1` <---- well that is not updating i

Comment: `parseFloat(i).toFixed(3)` <-- not doing anything

Comment: `i.toString()` <-- not doing anything

Comment: these lines of code do not alter `i`, they just run and do nothing. You need to set `i` to equal them. toFixed returns a string so unclear why you would call toString. `i = i + 0.1` and `alcoholData.push({
      'id': i,
      'name': i.toFixed(3) + "%"
    })`

Comment: ... and you should not alter `i` inside the loop, because once it's a String, doing `i += 0.1` on the next iteration will result in `i === "40.0000.1"` (String concatenation instead of addition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generator function that yields the current value and then wrap that in an array.

Also, the range *should* be inclusive/exclusive (`max = end - step`).

```js
const rangeGenerator = function*(start, end, step, fn) {
  for (let val = start; val < end; val += step) {
    yield fn ? fn(val) : val;
  }
}

let alcoholData = [...rangeGenerator(40, 95, 0.1, (val) => {
  return ((fixed) => ({ id : fixed, name : fixed + "%" }))(val.toFixed(3));
})]

console.log(alcoholData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```